# Dropdown with 'Delete' Request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

I allready asked something like that, but haven't got something that helped me out. So I'm sorry for asking again..

First I've created a Form with a submit button that directs me to my delete route. The Form had a 'DELETE' as a method.

```
{!! Former::danger_submit('Delete') !!}
{!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroythread", $comment->id)) !!}
{!! Former::close() !!}
```

This worked perfect. That means my controller function, the routes and the form haven't any mistakes.

Now I decided, that I want a dropdown. In the dropdown, there should be written: delete and edit. Lets focus on the delete.

The dropdown links looking like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
<li><a href="#">Edit</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Delete</a></li></ul> // <- Delete
```

I can't put my Laravel form inside this `<li>` tag of course.. Thats why I tried to do a link that directs me to my laravel delete route.

Like this:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('destroythread', $comment->id) }}">Delete</a></li>
```

but this haven't worked because this gives me a 'GET' request, not a 'DELETE'.

Well, now I'm stuck. I'm really sorry for asking this again..

I hope someone can help me out.

My laravel Delete Route is this:

```
Route::delete('/show/{id}', ['as' => 'destroythread', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@destroythread']);
```

and my Controller function is this:

```
public function destroythread($id) {
    $comment = Comment::query()->findOrFail($id);
    $comment->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

My last question about this problem couldn't help me out. A user said I can use ajax but I don't really understand how that works and don't really liked this way at all.

Thanks for any help!

Edit by @Joost answer:

```
                    {!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroythread", $comment->id)) !!}
                    <li><button>Delete</button></li>
                    {!! Former::close() !!}
```

worked but now there is a real button in my dropdown.. this don't look good. Is there any way that there just will stand a: Delete ?

Comment: Yes, thats my question from yesterday about the same problem. I only heard that I can use ajax but I never used that and don't really understand it.

Comment: You simply wrap the link in a form and change it to a button. You cannot use a href or link to send annything else than a GET request. Like in @Epodax his link.

Comment: could you show me how this looks like? Cause I tried it like this but haven't got it right. Maybe my syntax was wrong.

Comment: I updated my question with how i tried it with your answer. That worked but the now there is a really button in my dropdown and this of course don't look good.

Comment: @ItzMe488 Then simply strip its style with css and customize it to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You're saying that your form works. So you could just use a link instead of a button and simple JS like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.yourFormName.submit(); return false;">
```

Or you could try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="parentNode.submit(); return false;">
```

Comment: both haven't worked. I'm getting directed to my 404 page if I'm trying to use it like this.

Comment: Please try `{{ link_to_route('destroythread', 'D', $comment->id, ['data-method'=>'delete']) }}`

Comment: I did and this gives me : NotFoundHttpException :/ I allready tried it with link_to_route :/

Comment: Are you sure you've added `data-method="delete"` to a href link?

Comment: yes, I copy and paste it

Comment: Can you post output of a `php artisan routes` command please. You can update your post with a screenshot or copy-pasted text.

Comment: You cannot add a `data-method` attribute to an `<a>` as stated [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html)